# Depicting friend relationship between classes in UML

Tags: uml, friend

I have two classes A and B where B is a friend of A.

How to show this in UML ?

Is it ok to show it using dependency relation and then adding a comment on the relation like below ?

```
  <<Friend>>
```

B  ------------------>  A

Comment: What does it mean that a class is a friend of another? The semantics of this "relationship" would influence how it is represented

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly valid. For my own questions about UML, I  found [this website](http://www.csci.csusb.edu/dick/samples/uml1b.html) particularly helpful.

Comment: The link in your answer seems to be broken.